# Facebook get data

Tags: 8, social-network

I am not familiar in drupal 8. How do I get facebook information like posts, events, album, video? and want to be displayed as a node. can anyone help me on this.?

Answer (score 0):

You mean that you want people to register to you Drupal 8 site so they will be able to see their Facebook data?
With [Simple FB Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_fb_connect) you can give users the ability to register to Drupal by accepting the condition of your Facebook App and you'll be able to save data from their profile as nodes and display them later.

You need to use `hook_simple_fb_connect_registration` (see the function inside the module in order to understand how it works)